# Wrong result using ST_Intersection with postgis

Tags: postgresql, geometry, postgis, intersection

I am trying to do a simple intersection with postgis, but the result I get is wrong. There is a segment missing of about 7 meters at the start of the feature.

Here is the sql-command that I use for the intersection:

```
select ST_Intersection(t2.wkb_geometry,
                     t1.wkb_geometry), t2.sde_id as s_sde, t2.mtb_id,
ST_Length(ST_Intersection(t1.wkb_geometry,t2.wkb_geometry))
from
public.mountainbike_pavement_temp2 t1 inner join public.mountainbike_strecken_temp2 t2 on
t1.wkb_geometry && t2.wkb_geometry;
```

The result-length should be about 187 meters, but the result-length is only about 180 meters. I have tried a lot, but I cannot find any reason, why this happens, and thus how to fix it.

When I do this intersection in ArcGis, everything works as intended.

I tried this with
postgres 9.6.15 and postgis 2.4

and also with

postgres 12.1 and postgis 3.0, same results.

Tables and data can be found here:

https://pastebin.com/4vHqRYx5

https://pastebin.com/RAfzXXW6

Tablenames:
mountainbike_pavement_temp2
public.mountainbike_strecken_temp2

The distance of the first vertices from mountainbike_pavement_temp2 to mountainbike_strecken_temp2 is all 0, calculated with ST_Distance in postgis (see comment below). So I would assume, that there is an intersection.

[image]

Comment: Can you add the exact resultset you're getting from the query?

Comment: Could you add how you're computing this length in ArcGIS? Could it be that you're using different reference systems? Using `geometry` in WGS84 and `geography` I couldn't get the value you expect, but `~180`.

Comment: The reference system is allways the same, EPSG:31254.

Comment: When I use just a little buffer around one geometry, I get the correct intersection (you can see the different lengths in the two fields): `select ST_Intersection(ST_Buffer(t2.wkb_geometry, 0.00001),
       t1.wkb_geometry), t2.sde_id as s_sde, t2.mtb_id,
ST_Length(ST_Intersection(ST_Buffer(t2.wkb_geometry, 0.00001),
       t1.wkb_geometry)),
ST_Length(ST_Intersection(t1.wkb_geometry,t2.wkb_geometry))
from
public.mountainbike_pavement_temp2 t1 inner join public.mountainbike_strecken_temp2 t2 on
t1.wkb_geometry && t2.wkb_geometry;`

Comment: The result can be found here (ignore the first two rows): https://pastebin.com/GhT4C5Gr

Comment: that's odd. Could it be that they indeed do not overlap in this last 7m? Using a buffer it is expected that anything  overlapping it will be found. `WITH j AS (
  SELECT ST_Dump('SRID=31254;MULTILINESTRING((your very long geom))') as r
) 
SELECT 
  ST_AsText((j.r).geom), ST_AsText(t2.wkb_geometry),
  ST_Length(ST_Intersection(t2.wkb_geometry,(j.r).geom))
FROM j, mountainbike_pavement_temp2 t2`

Comment: As noted below exact intersections of lines is tricky.  What is the actual information you are trying to compute?  Using a buffer is a better idea, or possibly using some line matching techniques would work (as in this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/349017/14766)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `pavement` lines do not exactly coincide with the `strecken` lines.  Specifically, they contain a vertex `POINT ( -43663.049707713886 245429.5072260416 )` which does not lie on the `strecken` linestring.  This means the intersection does not include the entire length of the `strecken` line.

The picture below shows this (with the point location magnified to show the difference).  `pavement` is red, `strecken` is blue.

This may work in ArcGIS because it may use some snapping heuristic when computing the intersection.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your analysis. Which program are you using? With non of my programs (QGis, ArcGis) I am able to detect this gap. Even with postgis-database tools I cannot find it. I dumped the first 15 vertices to a separate table, and calculated the distance of each vertex to the mountainbike_strecken-line. The ouput is all 0.


Here is the code, that I use to calculate the distance:


   `select ST_Distance(t1.geom1, t2.wkb_geometry), t1.order1 from public.mountainbike_pavement_points t1 inner join public.mountainbike_strecken t2
     on t2.mtb_id = 20162;`

Comment: Can you calculate the distance to the line?

Comment: @user7882389 I don't think you're going to be able to get around this difference. It is important to note that your points have a really high precision. I'm not very familiar with this reference system, but I would guess it is entering the micriscopy realm ;) +1 to dr_jts for the detailed answer!

Comment: Yes, there seems to be just no solution with the tools that I have. What makes me feel a little bit nervouse is the fact, that even with databse-tools I do not have any chance to find out, if all points from pavement conincident with the strekcen-line.

Comment: @user7882389 reducing the geometry precision might be a good start. Exact overlap of lines / points with high precision can get quite annoying .. :)

Comment: But in this case it would make no difference if I reduce the precision (and in postgis you cannot set a precision, you are just able to use "ST_QuantizeCoordinates"), as there is no vertex on the mountainbike_strecken geometry near this point. So i would have to insert vertices in the original geometry. Still I think it is very strange, that ST_Intersects for this particular point gives "false", meaning no intersection, and ST_Distance gives a value of 0. This should not be the case. But maybe with this two together I can find the points that can cause trouble.

Comment: I'm using the JTS TestBuilder to work with the geometries you provided.  It has high accuracy and good tools for visualizing small differences.  Also, many of the algorithms are the same as in PostGIS (since it uses GEOS)

Comment: JTS computes the distance as 6.611191059663252E-13. It does look like PostGIS computes the distance between the line segment and the point as 0:  `SELECT ST_Distance('LINESTRING (-43665.78125 245442.2890625, -43661.46875 245422.109375)'::geometry, 'POINT (-43663.049707713886 245429.5072260416)'::geometry);`.  Not sure why that is. But the intersection is empty, which is the key point.

Comment: As I said, trying to do route analysis by using line intersections is tricky, due to computed points not lying exactly on lines.  It's better to use a buffer intersection or path matching techniques.  At some point it might be possible to provide a tolerance distance for spatial overlay operations, but that's not there yet.

Comment: Thanks agin for your detailed answers. But what I still don't get is, that even when I snap the first to the line (ST_ClosesPoint) the intersection fails. And ST_Distance says "0", but St_Intersects is false. But for a quick shot I will take the buffer-approach.

Comment: The reason that a snapped point may still not lie on a line is that lines have essentially infinite precision between their endpoints, whereas the constructed point necessarily has finite precision.  So it may still not lie on the line.

Comment: It's odd that PostGIS computes the point-line distance as 0.  This may be a quirk of the distance computation implementation, or may be an effect of numeric roundoff.

Comment: Another approach that works is using postgis.topology and adding both tables to a topology. A vertex is then created at that point in the mountainbike_strecken_temp2 and so the intersection works perfectly well. But I have very little experience with the topology extension, and I hope I do not run into serious performance troubles.